# C# asp.net SQL how to add new value to database by dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

the code below is my example of code how to connect and add by textbox what i want now is how to add with dropdownlist... code sample how to add by dropdownlist someone please???

```
public partial class SQL_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection;
        DataSet dataSet;
        string sql;
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myConnection = new SqlConnection("trusted_connection=yes;" + "database=DataBaseConnection;" + "connection timeout=30;");
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            sql = "SELECT Firstname,Surname FROM BasicInfo";
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, myConnection);
            //fill dataset
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "datafill");

            //bind database to gridviwe
            GridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand AddCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BasicInfo (Firstname,Surname) values(@a,@b)", myConnection);

            if (TextBox1.Text != null && TextBox2.Text != null)
            {
                //TextBox set Parameters
                AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", TextBox1.Text);
                AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", TextBox2.Text);

                //Execute Query
                AddCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //emptied textbox's
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                TextBox1.Text = "";

                //Redirect
                Response.Redirect("SQL-Test.aspx");
            }

            //close connection
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: "Add with a dropdown list"? What does it means

Comment: add new value to database by dropdownlist

Comment: @William: I don't understand your question but there is a mistake in your code. You should always check for IsPostback and only bind gridview in if(!IsPostback){...}

Comment: you can put dropdownlist and set DataTextField and DataValueField, DataTextField is the value that you want to show to user and DataValueField will most likely be some ID (number) but not necessary. You can get the value then in your button click event like drp.SelectValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected value from a dropdown you can access the Text property.

```
AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", TextBox1.Text);
AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", DropDownList1.Text);
```

Comment: TThank you so much sorry for the trouble :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to pass the selected value of dropdownlist to sql command? if so you can use
AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", Dropdownlist.SelectedValue); or
AddCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", Dropdownlist.SelectedText);

Comment: thank you so much for the help i forgot about it im so sorry for the trouble.